# Why am I unable to control the version of a grandchild dependency?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I upgraded the versions of a list of security vulnerabilities found in transitive dependencies but I am having trouble with one, which happens to be a grandchild dependency.

The child dependencies were easily remediated by adding something like this to the pom

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>child</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
        <version>${updated.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
```

However, this did not work for the grandchild. I moved it to the top of the dependencyManagement list to give it first priority but it it made no difference.

I find it hard to believe that a grandchild dependency would be treated differently, especially as I can't find any documentation about this issue, but this seems to be the only difference. Are there other factors to consider?

Comment: Please show parent pom and the full child pom ....otherwise it's impossible to help... Also which dependency is the problem..